# ¿Hay algún sinónimo para la palabra "berlin"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos

Hay una canción en castellano que se llama "A berlin (Chiquititas)¹", yo entiendo el concepto de *berlin* en la canción y en general, pero para mi sorpresa no hay en el diccionario rae la palabra "berlin". También no encontré en ningun otro diccionario y ni siquiera su uso en otras fuentes. ¿Esa palabra se usa solo en Argentina? ¿Hay algún sinónimo para la palabra "berlin"? Gracias a quien pueda contestarme.

¹: Si quieres mirar la canción la encontrarás en tu site favorito de canciones.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que se refiera a Berlín, la capital de Alemania.

Comment: Charlie, me parece que berlin es un juego o situación donde otras personas hablan de ti o te hacen preguntas.

Comment: Estoy con @Charlie. Debe ser Berlín, Alemania. Además como no tengo "un site favorito de canciones" deberías poner el link de "tu site favorito"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al menos en Argentina (de donde es oriunda la novela "Chiquititas"), en los juegos infantiles con prendas se manda a los castigados a Berlín.

En el DRAE encontramos esta definición de "[prenda](https://dle.rae.es/prenda)":

> 9. f. pl. Juego en que quien pierde tiene que entregar algo y hacer lo que se le mande para recuperarlo.

En los juegos infantiles, se manda al que pierde "a Berlín" mientras los demás niños deciden qué prenda (o castigo) asignarle al perdedor. "Berlín" viene a ser un lugar o espacio donde el perdedor permanece incomunicado por unos segundos mientras los demás planean en secreto cómo "castigarlo" por haber perdido.

Buscando en el Diccionario del Habla de los Argentinos, encuentro que la expresión "mandar a Berlín" está relacionada con la locución [en berlina](https://dle.rae.es/berlina), respecto de la cual el DRAE dice:

> 2. loc. adv. Arg. p. us. En algunos juegos, en situación de pena o castigo.

Comment: Gracias, Gustavson, yo pensé que el significado era más o menos eso pero no sabia un sinonimo para la palabra, veo ahora que podemos usar "prenda" para esos juegos en general. En portugués de Brasil se usa "berlinda" con un significado muy parecido y por eso mi sospecha.

Comment: En realidad, no diría que "Berlín" es sinónimo de "prenda". "Berlín" es la antesala donde el perdedor espera la definición de la prenda o castigo.

Comment: ¡Qué cosa tan curiosa! Sería interesantísimo ver en qué momento se creó esa asociación entre Berlín y cosa mal, ¿será alguna secuela de la 2.ª Guerra Mundial?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Me parece que está relacionado con las definiciones (1) y (3) del link que copié. Se debe haber usado "Berlín" en lugar de "berlinda" porque es un lugar y queda mejor con la frase verbal "mandar a..."

Answer (score 0):

La canción habla de Berlín, la capital de Alemania. Aunque aparece escrito “Berlin” o incluso “berlin”, la forma correcta en español es “Berlín” con *B* mayúscula y tilde en la *i*.

No tengo idea de por qué es Berlín y no otra ciudad o lugar. No creo que haya ningún mensaje implícito. Seguramente es algo que se le ocurrió a quien compuso la canción y usó la palabra porque va bien con el ritmo y la métrica.

Comment: Hola Pablo, veo que habla portugués de Brasil, yo pensé que no se trataba de la ciudad  porque en portugués de Brasil hay la palabra "berlinda" y esa palabra significa una situación donde personas te hacen preguntas o hablan de ti (como se pasa en la canción), y también hay una expresión en portugués "estar na berlinda" que significa eso o que está en peligro, yo pensé que era el caso de que esa palabra solo se usaba en Argentina prestada del portugués, dado que hacen frontera, pero veo que es argentino y no conoce con ese significado.

Comment: No, efectivamente, no conocía esa palabra en portugués. Quizá haya algún juego similar en Argentina que yo no conozco, pero si es así, nunca lo escuché nombrar.